# how to feed the ::base.html.twig with datas of database more proprely?

Tags: symfony

in my symfony application i use many controllers . They render their templates who all extend ::base.html.twig template. I feed these templates with an array of datas for  display the dynamic content , thanks to my controllers. But the ::base.html.template need also to receive his array of datas for display 4 pictures in a kind of slider . These datas (url of pictures) come from datas base and are available for all pages in my website so i'am asking myself how to send just one time this array of picture? For moment in every controllers I have to repeat the same code for get the url of pictures from database .
Sorry if my question is not clear

Comment: Make controller action that return slider with pictures and render it in your `base.html.twig` - `{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Base:fourPictures')) }}`

Comment: Ty very much that's exactly what i need I rush to try it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd personally move the code that creates these sliders out of the controllers into a service layer, be it a proper service or simply a class you create and use dependency injection you need to access things like the EntityManager within it. Services are fine, but they have an associated overhead.

By moving the code out of the controllers, you have a method you can call from all the controllers and one copy of the code, instead of multiple copies through your controllers.

Rendering controllers within twig is certainly possible, but it seems a bit of a fix for bad design (in my opinion anyway). It's a quick win, but not exactly an efficient one.

Remember, controllers should be thin, not bloated fat with code.

Comment: ty for this advise it's an interresting way

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way would be to create a Twig extension that will get this data for you.

Comment: You could do, but its probably easier, more efficient and easier to follow from a code reading point of view if its setup in the controller (ideally via a service layer method) and passed into the form, rather than the form doing the processing via an extension call.